# "Safe" pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am working on a project that involves a lot of serialization/deserialization from `Map[String, Any]` to some case classes. We usually know what the type of the key is going to be, so we use `unchecked` and cross our fingers that there is no bug elsewhere that would cause a `ClassCastException`, as in this trivial example:

```
def myIntParser(in: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Int] = in match {
  case out: Map[String, Int @unchecked] => out
}
```

Of course, this is scala and I am sure that we can do better. My question is how to write the following function:

```
// Returns Some(out) if 'in' can be safely cast as T,
// or None if in's type is not upper-bounded by T.
def safeCast[T: TypeTag](in: Any): Option[T] = ???
```

To simplify, our application only uses primitive types, Maps, Lists, Options and case classes with the same restrictions on their fields. The cost of traversing all the structure, unpacking, etc. is considered negligible.

Here is my current attempt, using some other answers on SO. It fails because I do not know how to compare the class of an object to a type symbol:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect._

// For early return
class CastFailException extends Exception("")

@throws[CastFailException]
def safeCastInternal[T](x: Any)(implicit ttag: TypeTag[T]): T = {
  val ev = typeOf[T]

  x match {
    case it: Iterable[_] if ev <:< typeOf[Iterable[Any]] =>
      val innerTpes = ev match {
        case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args
      }
      val innerTpe = innerTpes.headOption.getOrElse(throw new CastFailException)
      val tt = backward[Any](innerTpe)
      it.toList.map(x => safeCastInternal(x)(tt)).asInstanceOf[T]
    case y => ???
  }
}

val universe = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
// From another SO question
def backward[T](tpe: Type): TypeTag[T] =
  TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
    def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) =
      if (m eq mirror) tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
  })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast

Comment: Excellent, I had not thought of looking at shapeless. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing called - `serialization/deserialization from Map[String, Any] to some case classes`